# Pandas+Python - How to know when a value changes?

Tags: python, pandas

I've been working on a DataFrame, like the following extract and I want to know when the value changes:

```
     A     M     C
0   2.0    1    C1
1   2.0    1    C1
2   2.0    2    C1
3   2.0    2    C1
4   2.0    3    C1
5   2.0    3    C1
6   2.0    1    C2
7   2.0    1    C2
8   2.0    2    C2
9   2.0    2    C3
10  2.0    3    C3
11  2.0    3    C3
13  2.1    1    C3
14  2.1    1    C3
15  2.1    2    C3
16  2.1    2    C3
17  2.1    3    C3
18  2.1    3    C3
```

I know that A or C, changes always when M starts in 1. The question is how can I get the position every time M value starts in 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if your entire data set is built the same way as the one you are showing us but from what I can see you are searching for occurrence of 3 to 1 in the m columns which would result in a difference of -2 :

```
df[df['M'].diff()==-2].index
Out[101]: Int64Index([6, 13], dtype='int64')
```

let's say your M column always increases but it can go higher than 3, you could just look for the first occurrence of a negative number such has:

```
df[df['M'].diff()<0].index
Out[103]: Int64Index([6, 13], dtype='int64')
```

let's say there is no pattern there you could simply do:

```
df[(df['M'].diff()!=0) & (df['M']==1)].index
Out[104]: Int64Index([0, 6, 13], dtype='int64')
```

this is adding index 0 because `.diff()` will return NaN for the first index of the dataframe which is `!=0` and `df['M'] ==0`

Comment: This is enough to me. In fact, the ocurrence is 12 to 1(Months of a year). The result code is `df[df['M'].diff()==-11].index` . Thank you @StevenG

Answer (score 2):

Another way to determine when a new M set starts is to find where M is 1 and the previous M isn't:

```
In [18]: (df['M'] == 1) & (df["M"].shift() != 1)
Out[18]: 
0      True
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6      True
7     False
[.. and so on]
Name: M, dtype: bool
```

This includes the first element, but often makes sense.  Once you have this, you can take its cumulative sum to get a group number associated with each group (because True == 1 and False == 0):

```
In [19]: df["group_index"] = ((df['M'] == 1) & (df["M"].shift() != 1)).cumsum()

In [20]: df
Out[20]: 
      A  M   C  group_index
0   2.0  1  C1            1
1   2.0  1  C1            1
2   2.0  2  C1            1
3   2.0  2  C1            1
4   2.0  3  C1            1
5   2.0  3  C1            1
6   2.0  1  C2            2
7   2.0  1  C2            2
[.. and so on]
```

which is convenient because then you can use `groupby` to perform operations on the different clusters.

Comment: this would be about 30% faster than my answer in term of executing time.